# Click / conversion rate for each producer

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has tables:

- **Click Internal** - product clicks tracked by our system
- **Click External** - product clicks tracked by a partner system. Number of clicks: *click_internal >= click_external*, also for each external click there is a column with bool *click_external.click_valid*
- **Conversion** - purchases that happened after a click was tracked in partner system
- **Product** - information about product that was clicked or bought
- **Producer** - information about producer of the product

The database schema looks like this:
[image: database schema]

I would like to **show number of valid external clicks and conversions for each producer for given date**. So the result should look something like this:

[image: database result]

So far I got:

```
SELECT
producer.name,
COUNT(click_external.id),
COUNT(conversion.id),
SUM(conversion.price)
FROM click_external
LEFT JOIN click_internal ON click_internal.id = click_external.click_internal_id
LEFT JOIN product ON product.id = click_internal.product_id
LEFT JOIN producer ON producer.id = product.producer_id
LEFT JOIN conversion ON click_internal.id = conversion.click_internal_id
WHERE click_external.click_valid = 1
AND click_external.date = "2017-02-09"
GROUP BY producer.id
-- GROUP BY click_external.id
```

The problem is when I try to group by producer.id **the sum of COUNT(CLICK_EXTERNAL.id) column is greater than there are actually rows (clicks) in the DB.** i.e. Sum of clicks by each provider is greater than number of ungrouped clicks.

I have also tried to **group by click_external.id** (as seen in the code comment) to see which rows are there. The number of rows in result is ok, but **some rows are counted more times**. i.e. COUNT(CLICK_EXTERNAL.id) column is greater than 1 at some rows.

What should I change in the SQL?